# Retrieve a specific field Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want retrieve the account array if the query find role "elite"

i try with

```
db.users.aggregate(
{ $match : { "account.role" : "Elite" } }
);
```

But i have all object...

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("7623902143981943"),        
"account" : [ 
    {
        "role" : "Elite",            
        "action" : [ 
            "create", 
            "read", 
            "update", 
            "delete"
        ],
        "extra" : {
            account:[1,2,3,4]
        }
    },
 {
        "role" : "User",            
        "action" : [ 
            "create", 
            "read", 
            "update", 
            "delete"
        ],
        "extra" : {
            account:[10]
        }
    }
],
```

}

Can i retrieve only extra Array ( account:[1,2,3,4] ),if it is a positive result from the query? or I have to parse the received object? 
(the schema is very simplified, but I have many roles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind):

```
//Order of $unwind and $match matters
db.users.aggregate(
 {$unwind: "$account"},
 {$match : { "account.role" : "Elite" }},
 {$project : { "extra.account" : 1}}
);
```

**explanation**

$unwind splits the array into different elements. See the effect of

```
 db.users.aggregate({$unwind: "$account"})
```

then you match the elements with {"account.role": "Elite"}. See the effect of:

```
db.users.aggregate(
 {$unwind: "$account"},
 {$match : { "account.role" : "Elite" }}
);
```

And then you finally project just the desired fields

```
db.users.aggregate(
 {$unwind: "$account"},
 {$match : { "account.role" : "Elite" }},
 {$project : { "extra.account" : 1}}
);

//You can also remove the _id filed (included by default with:
db.users.aggregate(
 {$unwind: "$account"},
 {$match : { "account.role" : "Elite" }},
 {$project : { _id: 0, "extra.account" : 1}}
);
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You must use projection:
    db.users.aggregate(
     {$match : { "account.role" : "Elite" }},
     {$project : { "extra.account" : 1}}
    );

Besides, if you are just matching documents, there's no need to use the aggregation framewrok and you can just use:

```
// No projection here
db.users.find({"account.role" : "Elite"})
```

or

```
// Only returns the _id field + "extra.account" field if exists. By default the _id field is included
db.users.find({"account.role" : "Elite"}, { "extra.account" : 1}) 

// Only returns the "extra.account" field if exists
db.users.find({"account.role" : "Elite"}, { _id: 0, "extra.account" : 1})
```

Mongodb documentation can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Thanks, but i have this `error exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`

Comment: I've edited the answer to `aggregate({$match:..},{$project:...})`instead of `aggregate({$match:..,$project:...})`. Reference can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Thanks again but in my results i have two extra.account array Elite and and extra.account User... Can i retrieve only Elite?

Comment: thanks again, my result is http://pastebin.com/Q4KCyQUS . can't i have only account ?

Comment: Instead of `$project:{"extra.account" : 1}` use `$project:{my_desired_field_name: "$extra.account"}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47766/discussion-between-user3093439-and-enrique-fueyo)